# What step am I missing to edit Human Base Meshes assets?

Tags: asset-browser

Currently using Blender 3.3.1, but I suspect my problem isn't version specific.

[image: Attempting to use the base mesh]

I can drag the model I want from the asset browser into the viewport, and that works. However, I have no way of editing the mesh or going to sculpt mode. In the Scene Collection you can see the collections are expanded all the way, yet no mesh is displayed. In the mode tab, you can see I'm locked into Object Mode.

Convert to mesh does nothing.
Delete Hierarchy leaves me with an Empty.
Unlink leaves me with an Empty.
Instance to Scene creates a duplicate that is also missing it's mesh.

What am I missing to be able to shape a copy of the asset? Surely there's a way to do this without opening the original blend file.

Comment: Hello, it looks like a collection instance, what does it give if you select the object and Ctrl A > Make Instances Real?

Comment: @moonboots that's exactly what my problem was! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is a *Collection Instance*, select it and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Make Instances Real*.